# homomorphism from the proper Lorentz group to $ U(1)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-homomorphism

By the proper Lorentz group I mean the path connected component of the Lorentz group (I am considering the usual 3+1 space-time case), i.e., the set of elements which can be continuously linked to the identity element.

I suspect that the only homomorphism from the proper Lorentz group to the $U(1)$ group is the trivial map.

Is it true? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: Do you already know that the Lie algebra $o(3,1)$ is simple?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry, I just heard of this notion, but it does not make sense for me.

Comment: Do you know what this notion means? Using simplicity is the easiest way to solve the problem.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  No. I would be satisfied with a solution using only simple notions.